# PowerBIIntegration.Refresh() sometimes not work

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

What I do:

1. Create a PowerBI report in PowerBI Desktop, publish to Power BI service.
2. On Power BI service ,create a PowerApp embed in the PowerBI.
3. In PowerApp,there is a button which call PowerFlow to update data in SQLServer.

Expected:The PowerBI table should refresh

My problem is: On by button OnSelect event, I use '**PowerBIIntegration.Refresh();**' to refresh the PowerBI table,sometimes successfuly refresh, but sometimes the table not refresh.

My Button OnSelect Event:

```
If(
Delete.Run(
param1,
param2
),
Notify(
"Records updated successfully ",
NotificationType.Success,
1500
),
Notify(
"Records not updated",
NotificationType.Error
)
);
PowerBIIntegration.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Refresh() function for PowerBIIntegration() gets added to
> PowerApps during the visual on creation. Therefore it will not be
> available for existing PowerApps.

Based on the [following answer](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/PowerBIIntegration-Refresh-not-refreshing-the-report/m-p/301629/highlight/true#M86719), you cannot use the Refresh function is you're using an existing app. The Refresh function only works if you created a new App from within PowerBI from scratch.